# Image transformation of tif image does not work

Tags: image-transforms

I use craft transformations for resizing images. The transformation of jpg files works as exepted, but the transformation of a tif image does not work. Imagick is installed and in the backend it creats and shows thumbnails of the images. When i rename the image from .tif to .jpg it performs the transformation also.

The Twig code looks like this:

```
<img src="{{ entry.getUrl('preview') }}" width="200" height="200">
```

The output HTML Code of a tif image looks like this:

`<img src="http://www.am-sb-coop.ch/internal/img/AM_HC16_KW00_Broccoli_rl_ZTG_DL.tif" width="200" height="200">`

The output HTML Code of a jpg image looks like this:
`<img src="http://www.am-sb-coop.ch/internal/img/_preview/AM_FOOD_KW28_Prix_Gar_Konfi_mg_01_ZTG_DL.jpg" width="200" height="200">`

Is this a bug or have i missed a config setting?

Here are some images for explanation:

[image: Output in Browser]
[image: Backend shows Thumbnails]
[image: Transformation settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version `2.5.2750` it appears Craft now comes with sample files to check against `isImageManipulatable()` in `/craft/app/helpers/ImageHelper.php` which includes the following files located at `/craft/app/resources/images/samples/` by default:

- sample.bmp
- sample.gif
- sample.jpeg
- sample.jpg
- sample.png
- sample.svg
- sample.tif
- sample.tiff

If the installed [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) includes support for `tif` files it will be able to transform these without any extra configuration or hacking of the `isImageManipulatable()` function which was the only previous method of enabling transforms for `tif`. [Previous answer by @TomBauer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10534/4118).

Note: It looks like you should be able to add support for extra files in Craft (if supported by installed Imagick) by providing a sample file in the above directory for Craft to check against. At least until Craft updates.

Answer (score 3):

I found the way to create thumbnails of tif files. You have to change the function isImageManipulatable in the file /craft/app/helpers/ImageHelper.php:

```
public static function isImageManipulatable($extension)
{
    $extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'wbmp', 'xbm');

   if (craft()->images->isImagick())
    {
        $extensions[] = 'svg';
    }

    return in_array(mb_strtolower($extension), $extensions);

}
```

To this:

```
public static function isImageManipulatable($extension)
{
    $extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'wbmp', 'xbm');

   if (craft()->images->isImagick())
    {
        $extensions[] = 'svg';
        $extensions[] = 'tif';
    }

    return in_array(mb_strtolower($extension), $extensions);

}
```

I know, changing core code is not a real solution: i posted this change as a Craft feature request -> http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/8794456-better-support-of-image-types-in-image-transformat

Comment: Whether or not tif is supported depends on Imagick configuration. TIFF also requires an external library (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) so it most likely is not one of the formats supported by default on most hosts. Perhaps we'll add a config setting that would allow you to define additional extensions, but I can't give any guarantees.

Comment: A config setting would be realy great! Thx for "check" this option.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, only `jpg`, `jpeg`, `gif`, `png`, `wbmp` and `xbm` files are supported for image transforms using [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) and [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).  Additionally, if you have Imagick installed, Craft will also transform `svg` files.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I found now a way to create the thumbnails from tif files. See solution above.